# How can I handle multiple inplace grids on a single page in Tapestry 5?

Tags: tapestry

I want to put multiple grids on a page. When the user clicks the column heading to sort or uses the pager, I'd like to be able to change the state in place. However, I'm not sure what events are triggered on the server side or how to determine which grid was modified. The grids are in a loop so Tapestry generates the ids. I need something like a context for the grid so I can use onSort(String grid) or similar. Any ideas?

Comment: hi @Brian i am facing the same prob. did you find any solution? if yes then please share with me. you can check the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653094/dynamic-id-to-grid-component-in-tapestry-5

Comment: @MahendraAthneria I have not found a solution. Right now I am just not using in-place so when the user sorts the grid, it refreshes the entire page. Not an ideal user experience, but at least it works. I added a comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The event name is "sort". It triggers the updateSort(columnId) of the grid model;
I guess you could provide a custom gridModel (which knows which grid it's for) where you can handle the sorting.

Or you could override the default grid header for each column by adding a parameter:

```
<p:propertyheader>
    <t:eventlink context="a,b,c" event="sort">property</t:eventlink>
</p:p
```

(propertyheader is a combination of propertyname and the ending "header")