# Dynamic ID to Grid Component in Tapestry 5

Tags: dynamic, grid, tapestry

Can i assign dynamic ID to Grid component?

for example, i have a grid inside the loop and i am not able to assign the dynamic id for the grid.

```
<t:loop source="listOfAttachmentVOList" value="attachmentVOList" t:index="index">
     <t:grid t:source="allCelebrities" t:id="myGrid"/>
</t:loop>
```

in above code ID is "myGrid" but that is not dynamic.

is there any way to assign the ID dynamically?

Regards,
Mahendra

Comment: Do you need the dynamic id for JavaScript functionality or to do something on the server side using an event?

Comment: @BrianDeterling i need dynamic ID for the server side to use the events. do you have any idea for that?

Comment: No, that's the problem I'm having. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, someone will have a workaround.